# Public bigquery dataset with partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata

I'm searching for an example for a bigquery public dataset containing a partitioned table.

I searched https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. `goolge_analytics_sample` dataset contains the partitioned table `ga_sessions`

https://www.ga4bigquery.com/how-to-query-multiple-tables-with-table-suffix-ua/